# "IndexedSet", "MapSet" or "SetMap" implementation in Java

Tags: java, collections, guava

I'm looking for a `Set` implementation in Java that provides lookup based on elements properties. Thinking in Guava terms it could be constructed using a `Function<Element, SearchKey>` (expected to be unique across all set elements) and providing a method `find(SearchKey key)` returning an `Element` for which the function would return `key`.

Obvious **assumptions** that would need to be satisfied:

- Result of `function(element)` is constant for the whole lifetime of `element` in the set.
- function gives unique results for all set elements

**Reason:** 
Sometimes there is a need for `Set<Element>` and the field type cannot be changed into a `Map<SearchKey, Element>` (like in JPA Entities or in case of 4rd party code). Still, when constructing such an object one could safely use their own `Set` implementation with `Map`-like capabilities.

**Alternatives:**

There are some alternatives I've already found, none of which seems perfect

- not having `Map`-like capabilities - using linear search for `find(SearchKey)` implementation (works with every `Set` implementation:)
- using `TreeSet` with `Comparator` comparing `SearchKeys` - a bit like a **hack**, especially that this no longer respects element equality
  the "find" method is called `ceiling` and requires that you construct artificial `Element` for lookup purposes (uogh...)
- "equivalence set" (http://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries/issues/detail?id=576) - but that is not implemented and does not seem to be going to be

(**If you would like to answer** that you don't know any more alternatives -- save your time and don't. This is something I already know, I will not be able to accept your answer.)

Comment: Do you definitely need to have a *single* object serving both roles, or could you have the set and then index it separately e.g. with `Maps.uniqueIndex`? You could always create your own type which uses that idea combined with composition and delegation to expose both sets of interfaces from a single object.

Comment: Well your reason part says why you still need a `Set` - it doesn't explain why you can't have *both*.

Comment: You mean e.g. to subclass a `HashSet` and have an additional "index" field being a map and managed it by myself? Would do but still a bit error prone.

Comment: If I could add a new type, I would just add `Map<SearchKey, Element>` and be happy with this elegant approach. In cases like JPA beans or 3rd party data store you don't want / can't add a new field besides existing `Set<Element>`, so this solution is applicable only to some of the cases.

Comment: I was suggesting using composition rather than inheritance, actually. A new type with two fields (a map and a set) where methods delegated to one or both of them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I must be missing something, otherwise it's pretty easy via `ForwardingSet` to `HashBiMap.keySet()`. My [trivial implementation](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/4971686/published/maaartin/so/IndexedSet.java) only cares about `add` and `addAll`, all the other stuff should work without any effort. There's no single test, I'd recommend to use Guava testlib for this.

Comment: nice. though not a library :)

Comment: But nearly... the `BiMap` does nearly all the work. You could try to persuade the Guava guys to add this feature, but I'm pretty sceptical as I've never heard about anybody needing it. Though I'm sure, I wanted this some long time ago.

Answer (score 3):

> I'm looking for a Set implementation in Java that provides lookup based on elements properties.

This is what a Map is for and yes, you do need to build a key object to represent what if being looked up.

This is the simplest and more efficient solution in Java, so while it is slightly unpleasant, I wouldn't worry about it.

BTW: Sets are typically implemented as a layer over a Map in the JRE, which isn't ideal IMHO.

Comment: Unfortunately `Map` does not have an `add(Element)` method which would compute the key for the caller. Besides, I think I've said that I'm limited to `Set<Element>` as a data type which `Map` does not implement AFAIK. In cases when I *can change* data type -- I'm all with you, sanity and the `Map`.

Comment: How complicated is it to write such a method or sub-class the Map to do this?  If deriving a key yourself is so difficult, I suggest changing your model so it is not.  Why are you limited to Set given Collection has a exactly the same methods.

Comment: You're right! `IndexedCollection` would do as well. Is there any existing implementation? If not, I would stay with my workaround-ish `TreeSet`.

Comment: I wouldn't suggest sub-classing library classes.  It's looking for trouble next major JVM upgrade.

Comment: @VeronicaCornejo Good point, while sub-classing is an option, it is unlikely to be the best option.  Much better to add this code to something which wraps the collection.

Answer (score 2):

If I understand your question correctly, 2 alternatives come to my mind:

1. A variant of your hack:  a `TreeSet` with a comparator that compares `YourSearchKey` with `YourElement`.  You can either trick the type system, or create a common interface `YourAbstractSearchKey`.  Only drawbacks are that:

   - `YourSearchKey` objects could be inserted in the `Set`.  `Collections.checkedSet()` could help in this point.
   - Result of searches would most probably need to be cast to `YourElement`.  Workaround:  define all the properties in the common interface `YourAbstractSearchKey` and have implementation `YourSearchKey` throw `UnsupportedOperationException` for the extra ones.
2. Similar, but with a Map.  You don't need to add extra properties to `YourAbstractSearchKey` because the Map would be `Map<YourAbstractSearchKey,YourElement>`.  To add elements you would need to write `myMap.put(newElement,newElement)`.

Comment: Woow. I did not think about this. This is very much along my general hackish approach :)

Comment: (Map won't do -- if it did, I would just `Map<SearchKey, Element>`)

Comment: @PiotrFindeisen Yes, that's pretty much what I said RE `Map`s.